# Require assistance with correcting the following code

Tags: java

I dont understand what I am doing wrong here. I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Student.paint(Student.java:19)
    at School$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(School.java:127)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

The following code is supposed to draw a rectangle for whatever grade the user types using the textfield:

```java
public class Student extends Person {

    static Graphics g;

    public static void paint(Graphics g, int gradelevel) {
        if (gradelevel == 9) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
        } else if (gradelevel == 10) {
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillOval(200, 200, 100, 100);
        } else if (gradelevel == 11) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(200, 200, 100, 100);
        } else if (gradelevel == 12) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(200, 200, 100, 100);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How/where do you call your `paint` method?

Comment: i call it in a main gui menu

Comment: i call the paint method in the main class

Answer (score 1):

You declared

```
 static Graphics g;
```

and `g`  never initialized. so when you called    `g.setColor(Color.green);`, `NullPointerException`

Just realized that there are two g's in your code.

```
 public static void paint(Graphics g, int gradelevel)
```

So while calling paint method you might passing the   `static Graphics g;`  which remained un initialized.

For more accurate answer please show, how you are calling `paint` method.

Comment: what do i initilize g to

Comment: `g` is also a parameter, so it's when calling the method that a `null` must be given.

Comment: @sp00m Yes. I guess that `g` only passed to this method.

Comment: so do: static Graphics g=null

Comment: i call the paint method in a main gui menu

Comment: i tried setting the static Graphics g to null in both the student class and the main class

Comment: i call the method in a school class like this:

Comment: if (e.getSource()==create1)
            {
                String schoolname=enterschool.getText();
                int gradelevel=Integer.parseInt(entergrade.getText());
                Student create=new Student();
                create.paint(g,gradelevel);
            }

Comment: can someone tell me what im doing wrong and how i can fix the program

Answer (score 0):

For graphics application, you need to `extends` a Container (e.g `JFrame`, `JPanel`) than override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. Look at following code sample. Otherwise, declare a non-initialized `Graphics` class will throw `NPE`.

```
public class Student extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
        ..............
    }
}
```